# Rust constants in different modules?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have this "main.rs" file which I declare a version constant.

```
pub const VERSION: &'static str = "v2";
mod game;
fn main() {
   do_stuff();
}
```

Then I want to access this global constant in a different module "game.rs":

```
pub fn do_stuff() {
   println!("This is version: {}", VERSION);
}
```

How do I make the constant available everywhere?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

As `VERSION` is declared in `main.rs`, which is a crate root, you can access it using its absolute path: `crate::VERSION`<sup>1</sup>.

This should work:

```
pub fn do_stuff() {
    println!("This is version: {}", crate::VERSION);
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> In Rust 2015, `::VERSION` could be used, but [starting in Rust 2018](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/path-changes.html), `crate` is required.

Comment: How do we do for a u64 type of field?

Comment: Note, in modern Rust you should use "crate::Version"

Comment: What @RandomInsano said. This answer needs a little update, it's no longer valid

Comment: what If I declared it in mod.rs?

Answer (score 1):

```
use crate::VERSION
println!("version: {}", VERSION);
```

will be better.